# how to send or convert JSON(attach a file) to byte array over MQTT?

Tags: android, mqtt

I am doing my final year project, I need send a JSON which attach a file to MQTT broker which are only can publish in byte array format. If I using `.toString().getByte()` then the file data would be lost.

```
JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
    json.put("command", "123");
    json.put("reserve","123");
    json.put("file", fullyReadFileToBytes(file));

MqttMessage message2 = new MqttMessage(json.toString().getBytes("utf-8"));
mqttAndroidClient.publish(subscriptionTopic,message2 );
```

How can I send it ?

Comment: Hint: you can't embed the raw bytes of the file and it still be valid json anyway. Look for a way to encode the file as a string.

Comment: OK, Thank you, i found a way to encode it to string and successfully send.

Comment: Feel free to add your solution as an answer and accept it, I just wasn't prepared to do your project for you.

Answer (score 1):

I try on this coding, and it can send the file with the byte.

```
String encoded = Base64.encodeToString(fullyReadFileToBytes(file), Base64.DEFAULT);

json.put("file", encoded);

MqttMessage message2 = new MqttMessage(json.toString().getBytes("utf-8"));

mqttAndroidClient.publish(subscriptionTopic,message2 );
```